# Continuous deployment with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, github-actions

Could anyone tell what’s wrong with this GitHub workflow?

```
name: Distribute

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  
  build_apk:
    name: Build Flutter (Android)
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
          channel: 'stable'
    - run: flutter pub get
    - run: flutter build apk
    - name: Upload APK
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
      with:
        name: App
        path: ${{ github.workspace }}/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
    - name: Upload APK
      uses: wzieba/Firebase-Distribution-Github-Action@v1.3.2
      with:
        appId: ${{secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID}}
        token: ${{secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN}}
        groups: testers
        file: ${{ github.workspace }}/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
        debug: true
```

I've tried everything with it, it keeps returning error 400, file not found in body request.

Comment: Flutter build defaults to release, so I suspect there is no debug apk and that the path does not exist

Comment: oh, so you mean the name of the file is wrong! will give it a try, very likely it's that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @frankenapps, I was able to solve the problem, the flutter build instruction returns a path that is something like build/app/output/flutter-apk/release, it's hidden in the logs that follow the instruction, after using it instead of the usual paths in other tutorial everything works like a charm.

And thanks to @Zsolt for the edit.